# Unable to open Specflow feature file in VS2017 7.6 (for MAC)

Tags: macos, xamarin, specflow, xamarin.uitest

I just downloaded the latest version of VS for MAC (7.6).
I have a UITest project and use SpecFlow features to design these tests.

Since the new update, I can no longer open these .feature files. A blank file is displayed instead. And a blank error message is displayed.

My project still builds and runs though. I just cant adjust the .feature file.
ON my windows PC, this is not a problem. But I mainly develop on the MAC.

I use specflow 1.9.1 / xamarin uitest 2.2.4.dev?? / and nunit 2.6.4.
Any ideas what the problem could be? OR how I can find out exactly where the problem comes from?

Thanks